# Save all color editings as a mapping in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, color-correction

Am I dreaming, or do I recall reading something about being able to "save a color table" or "save color transformations" or somesuch, which has the effect of "canning" all old-to-new colors no matter how they were created in Photoshop, in various steps in destructive editing.  This can then be applied to another similar image to redo the total of the changes.

This is not related to saving presets of some adjustment layer:  I know about those, and it's not what I'm asking.

In this case, I used a (destructive) filter, and eventually saved the file.  I also have a copy of the original, so I can look at the difference between them.  The description I remember reading is exactly what I could use here: look at the old->new color values and do the same mapping to a different image.

Is this something no longer supported, or from some other tool?  I can't find anything like it now.

Comment: [maybe a gradient map adjustment layer is what you are looking for](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31468/how-can-i-adjust-or-replace-many-colours-in-an-image-with-a-new-swatch-of-colour)

Comment: Gradient map keys off the Luminance in the original, not complete colors, so that doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you're describing is the [creation of color lookup tables](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/export-color-lookup-tables.html) in more recent versions of Photoshop (CC 2014). It allows you to create a map of original to new values and then apply that to other images as you desire.

Look under: File -> Export -> Color Lookup Tables

Fill in the information and done. You will need adjustment layers for this to work.

Quick note: to use them, add a new color lookup adjustment layer to your target image. You'll get a dialog you can use to import the lookup table.

Comment: Nice to know where I saw it, but too bad that it won't work for me. If I had ajustment layers I could just copy those to another image. I have a *before* and an *after* image.  Maybe there is a way to generate a layer using some function.

Comment: @JDługosz - You might be able to use the reference image as a way of setting up the original with adjustments. A bit fussy, but might get you close.